# JS - insert form value into URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a clickable URL, it's a bit beyond my JS knowledge.

The target URL is i.e.: `https://www.apple.com/at/shop/buy-iphone/iphone-se`

The created `at/` - works fine. I did manage to change the i.e. `iPhone SE` string to `iphone-se` but I struggle to put (append) the `iphone-se` string into the URL string. So both are working, but not together.

This the current status:

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
  $('.model').html($(this).val().toLowerCase().replace(" ","-"));
});

$('#foo-list').change(function() {
    var opt = $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]);
    var url = opt.attr('data-url');
 $('#url').html('<a href="https://www.apple.com/'+url+'shop/buy-iphone/" target="_blank"  >Apple product site</a>');

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="paselect" id="foo-list">
<option data-country="Australia" data-iso="AUD" data-cur="A$" data-url="au/"  >Australia</option>
<option data-country="Austria" data-iso="EUR" data-cur="&amp;euro;" data-url="at/" >Austria</option>
<option data-country="Brazil" data-iso="BRL" data-cur="B$" data-url="br/" >Brazil</option>
</select>

  <input name='model' type="text" value="iPhone " ><p>
  
   
  <span class="model"></span><br>
  <span id='url'></span><br>
```

Comment: so you're trying to keep `/at` even when directly editing the input?

Comment: you can get the value in your input field if you attach an id to the html element: `<input name='model' type="text" value="iPhone " id="the-phone"><p>`  and in your change handler function `var phone = $('#the-phone').val()`,  but you would need to map this to the value you want in the URL string.  You are probably better off making this a dropdown list,  with the text value, of each option, being friendly display text, and the value of the option, the string you want in your URL.

Comment: Yes, I need the `au/` or `at/` in the URL. But that part works fine. The append part is the trouble. I want to create the link with out a page refresh (otherwise I would use the more familiar php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
$('#foo-list').change(function() {
    var opt = $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]);
    var url = opt.attr('data-url');
    var model = $("input[name='model']").val().toLowerCase().replace(" ","-");
    $('#url').html('<a href="https://www.apple.com/'+url+'shop/buy-iphone/' + model + '" target="_blank"  >Apple product site</a>');      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="paselect" id="foo-list">
  <option data-country="Australia" data-iso="AUD" data-cur="A$" data-url="au/">Australia</option>
  <option data-country="Austria" data-iso="EUR" data-cur="&amp;euro;" data-url="at/">Austria</option>
  <option data-country="Brazil" data-iso="BRL" data-cur="B$" data-url="br/">Brazil</option>
</select>

<input name='model' type="text" value="iPhone ">
<p>
  <span id='url'></span><br>
</p>
```

Comment: @yello Glad that I was able to help :)

Comment: Just a few notes:
Works with jquery 3.3.1 - not sure about older versions. 
The model to URL works only when I input the model first, and not when I input the country first. (no problem for me). 
To create appends like iphone-11-pro I changed `replace(" ","-");` to `replace(\ \g ,"-");` so all white spaces get replace and not just he first one.